First nonzero derivative of real analytic non-negative function is positive
Let $f:[0,1)\to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a real analytic, 1-periodic function. Moreover, assume that $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.
$\textbf{Claim.}$ Let $n$ be the smallest non-negative integer such that $f^{(n)}(0) \ne 0$, then $f^{(n)}(0) > 0$.
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ This feels true as
$$
f(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n + \mathcal{O}(x^{n+1}).
$$
Since as $x\to 0$, $\mathcal{O}(x^{n+1})$ contributes so little, forcing $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n > 0$ in order to avoid a contradition. However, I'm not sure how to make this idea rigorous.

In what sense is $f$ $1$- periodic if it isn’t even defined outside the $[0,1)$ interval?

assume $f^{(n)}(0) =-c, c >0$ and pick $x$ very small so $c/n!>Ax$ where $|f(x)/x^n-f^{(n)}(0) /n!| <Ax$ for $x$ near $0$; this immediately implies that $f(x)<0$ for such small enough $x$ which is not possible

Assume $f^{(n)}(0)<0$. Then, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{ \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n + \mathcal{O}(x^{n+1})}{x^n}=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}<0$$
This implies that $\dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}$ must be negative in some neighbourhood of $0$. In particular, for $x>0$ sufficiently small this means that $f(x)<0$, a contradiction with the non-negativity of $f$.
